# Scheme: Mutating elements in an array for chess

Tags: arrays, scheme, chess, mutable

I have been working on a simple chess program in Scheme, and one of the helper functions that I have defined consumes a piece, and its coordinates (current-location) and places it at specified coordinates (move-here) on the chess board, switching out any piece that may be located at the Move-here coordinates. The function was working as I had hoped, yet now for whatever reason it is no longer functioning properly. I have no idea what could be causing this, and have been tracing and re-tracing the code for a while now trying to find the bug. I am hoping someone may be able to shed light on the situation.

Here is the code for the piece-switching function, along with the structures used within the code:

```
(define-struct place (row column piece))
;; Place is a structure (make-place r c p) where r is the rank of a piece
;; which is a symbol of 'Pawn, 'Rook, 'Knight, 'Bishop, 'King or 'Queen
;; and column and place. Together c and p give the placement coordinates,
;; where column is one symbol from '(a b c d e f g h) and row is a number from 
;; 1 - 8 inclusive.

(define-struct piece (rank color))
;; Piece is a structure (make-piece r col) where rank is as described for a place   structure, 
;; and colour is a symbo either 'black or 'white.

(define move-counter 1) ; Keeps track of the current number of mves made.
;; Odd indicates white to move, else black to move.

;; Swap-in: '(Symbol Symbol Nat) '(Symbol Nat) -> '(-2- void)
;; Conditions:
;;   Pre: Swap-in is '(rank column row) From is '(column row)
;;   Post: produces list of lists containing -2- and void. where void represents
;;         any changed values.
;; Purpose: Swap-piece is a helper for any X-Move function that dictates the legal
;;          moves of a given piece.

(define (swap-piece swap-in from)
  (map (λ (x)
         (map (λ (piece)
                (cond
                  [(and (= (third swap-in) (place-row piece)) 
                        (symbol=? (second swap-in) (place-column piece)))
                   (set-place-piece! piece 
                                     (make-piece (first swap-in) (cond
                                                                   [(odd? move-counter)     'white]
                                                                   [else 'black])))]
                  [(and (= (second from) (place-row piece))
                        (symbol=? (first from) (place-column piece)))
                   (set-place-piece! piece (make-piece empty empty))]
                  [else void]))
              x)) 
       board))
```

Here are two examples; the first of which is what it outputs, and the second is what
it should output (in the example, there is a small modification to Swap-piece so that one of its parameters is a board, as to not use the entire array I have for my chess board).

```
(define Example-board (list
                         (list
                          (make-place 8 'a (make-piece 'Rook 'black))
                          (make-place 7 'a (make-piece 'Pawn 'black)))
                         (list
                          (make-place 4 'a (make-piece 'Queen 'white))
                          (make-place 6 'b (make-piece 'King 'White))))) 

> (swap-piece '(Queen a 4) '(a 7) Example-board)
(shared ((-2- void)) (list (list -2- (void)) (list (void) -2-)))
```

So I call Example Board to get the updated board:

```
> Example-board
(list
 (list 
  (make-place 8 'a (make-piece 'Rook 'black)) 
  (make-place 7 'a (make-piece empty  empty)))
 (list 
  (make-place 4 'a (make-piece 'Queen 'white)) 
  (make-place 6 'b (make-piece 'King  'White))))
```

However, the output I expect is:

```
> Example-board
(list
 (list 
  (make-place 8 'a (make-piece 'Rook 'black)) 
  (make-place 7 'a (make-piece 'Queen 'white)))
 (list 
  (make-place 4 'a (make-piece empty empty)) 
  (make-place 6 'b (make-piece 'King  'White))))
```

Sorry, for the long post, however I just cannot figure out what is causing this to happen. As I said, I am sure this code was working just a few hours ago.

EDIT: I should add that the list, board, that the map function is acting on in my Swap-piece function is the chessboard.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scheme function that stopped working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21592853/scheme-function-that-stopped-working)

Comment: Indeed, this is a x-post that got migrated.

Comment: @jozefg yes, it is. I posted it at programmers too. Didn't know where it should be.

Comment: No problem, likely what'll happen is this will get closed and people will answer the original posted on stackoverflow. PS in the future the good citizen approach is to post here if you think it belongs here, and let mods/community migrate it if you were mistaken :)

Comment: @jozefg Thanks for letting me know, I will definitely remember that. Also, I figured it out, so I deleted the other question and will be deleting this question too, unless I shouldn't?

Comment: If you want, you could answer it yourself so that if someone else has a similar problem they'd benefit from this question too! Plus people will likely upvote and you get internet points :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realised what was causing the incorrect piece placing/swapping. I had the swap part backwards, almost surely because I labelled my parameters incorrectly. My code basically said: "If the coordinates of the square I'm looking at are equal to the coordinates of the piece I am placing, don't change the square", which defeats the purpose of moving a piece, obviously. For anyone who is interested, the proper code is:

```
(define (swap-piece swap-in from)
  (map (λ (x)
         (map (λ (piece)
                (cond
                   ; comparing coordinates of current square to swap-in
                  [(and (= (third swap-in) (place-row piece)) 
                        (symbol=? (second swap-in) (place-column piece)))
                   ; If they are equal place, remove swap-in from that square
                   (set-place-piece! piece (make-piece empty empty))]
                   ; If the coordinates of the square equal the coordinates of From
                   ; place the swap-in piece there
                  [(and (= (second from) (place-row piece))
                        (symbol=? (first from) (place-column piece)))
                   (set-place-piece! piece 
                                     (make-piece (first swap-in) (cond
                                                                   [(odd? move-counter)  'white]
                                                                   [else 'black])))]
                  [else void]))
              x)) 
       board))
```